# There is an error on trying to run grunt watch

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Whenever I run `grunt watch` I get the following error:

`` grunt[48126]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:627:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 0x10003a5ab node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000396aa node::AddEnvironmentCleanupHook(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(void*), void*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x10005d027 node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001d2524 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x1001d18ce v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<true>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x1001d134a v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x12a0f384fb7d 
Abort trap: 6 ``

I have grunt-cli@1.3.2 installed globally and the following on local dev dependencies in my project:

`"grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-grunticon": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-includes": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^2.1.0",`

Answer (score 3):

So I had my node at 11.0.0 which wasn't compatible with grunt. I downgraded it to 8.1.0 and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
npm i natives
```